# How to navigate to pages from parent component to child with dynamic header and back?

Tags: reactjs

[image]  onClick of events I'm able to route to pages but with warnings. The dynamic header which I have created are not changing accordingly. How do I rectify this?

> parent component

```
 [![UserLogin.js:- 

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './UserLogin.module.scss';
import Email from '../Email/Email'
import Password from '../Password/Password';
import SignUp from '../SignUp/SignUp'
import PhoneLogin from '../PhoneLogin/PhoneLogin';
import Back from '../../../Assets/Images/Back.png'

// let passLogin, otpLogin, createAccount, emailLogin
class UserLogin extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            emailLogin:true,
            otpLogin:false,
            socialLogin:false,
            createAccount:false,
            passLogin:false,
            headerText:'Login '
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        **//change header text based on values clicked like email login, otp, login etc**

        //or onlcick of any button change the header text
        if(this.state.emailLogin || this.state.passLogin){
            this.setState({headerText: 'Login'})
        }
        else if(this.state.createAccount) {
            this.setState({headerText: 'Create Account'})
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ headerText: 'Verify Account'})
        }
    }

    handleBack() {
        if(this.state.passLogin || this.state.otpLogin || this.state.createAccount){
            this.setState({ emailLogin: true, passLogin: false, otpLogin:false, createAccount:false})
        }
    }
**onclick of this back, page routing should happen** 

    continueHandler() {
        this.setState({passLogin: true, emailLogin: false})
    }

    otpHandler() {
        this.setState({otpLogin: true, emailLogin: false})
    }

    otpPageHandler() {
        this.setState({passLogin:false, otpLogin:true})
    }

    createAccount() {
        this.setState({createAccount: true, emailLogin: false})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.login_container}>
                <div className={styles.login_mid_container}>
                    <div className={styles.card_header}>
                    <span className={styles.back} onClick={this.handleBack}>
                        <img className={styles.image} src={Back} />
                        Back
                    </span>
                    <div className={styles.head}>{this.state.headerText}</div>
                        {/* back button div */}
                        {/* header text dynamic*/}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.emailLogin ? <Email continue = {this.continueHandler.bind(this)} otp = {this.otpHandler.bind(this)} create = {this.createAccount.bind(this)} /> : 
                            this.state.passLogin ? <Password otpPage = {this.otpPageHandler.bind(this)} /> :
                                this.state.createAccount ? <SignUp /> :
                                    this.state.otpLogin ? <PhoneLogin /> : ''
                        }
                        {/* // form section */}
                        {/* call ur respective component e.g <emailLogin /><otpLogin />  */}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserLogin;
```

> child 1 out of three.

```
Email.js:-


render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <form>
                    <div className={styles.input}>
                        <label className={styles.label}>Registered Email ID or Phone Number</label>
                        <input className={styles.mail} type='text' name='email' value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleInputChange} placeholder='Enter Registered Email ID or Phone Number' />
                    </div>
                    <button type='submit' className={styles.button} onClick={emailValid? this.props.continue : phoneValid? this.props.otp: ''} disabled={!this.state.formValid}>Continue</button>
                    <hr className={styles.hr} />
                    <div className={styles.social}>
                        <div>
                            <button className={styles.facebook}>
                                <img src={Facebook} className={styles.logo} />
                                <span className={styles.fb}> Login with facebook</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button className={styles.google}>
                                <img src={Google} className={styles.logo} />
                                <span className={styles.Google}>Login with Google</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className={styles.new}>New Here? <span onClick={this.props.create} className={styles.create}>Create an Account</span></p> **this is a link to navigate, I'm able to navigate with warning**
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>                
            </div>
        )
    }][1]][1]
```

> A parent component has 3 child components, on routing , the dynamic header has to change accordingly. I have included the warning screenshot with this.
>
> what is expected is : to navigate to different pages with the change in header(dynamic)
> actual result : I'm able to navigate but with warnings and the header is not changing, "back" is not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this piece of code ,

```
onClick={emailValid? this.props.continue : phoneValid? this.props.otp: ''}
```

As the error states you are returning a empty string to the `onClick` instead of a function . so you need to make sure that you are passing a function here instead of empty string .

Also you can do few refactors in your code ,

1. you need to bind your `this.handleBack` as you are doing for other class methods . But instead of manually writing `bind(this)` in your code you can change your class methods as arrow functions . `handleBack = () => { .... }` with this in place you can just do onClick={this.handleBack}
2. Avoid nested ternary in your code as it will be confusing instead use conditional rendering via `&&` .

```
    {this.state.email && <Email .... />}
    {this.state.passLogin && <Login ... />}
```

Comment: Since i am using callback function from the parent to render the page conditionally based upon the validation then how can i use the && approach in the onClick event.